# iPhone - Changing label text into a TableView "header"

Tags: iphone, uitableview, text, uilabel

I've created this view using XCode4, dropping a UILabel onto the top part of a UITableView.
The Label is connected to an IBOutlet of the File's owner but I can't change it programmaticaly.

[image]

That part of text doesn't seem to be into a header. Where is it ?
**And the most important, how may I change it or best : hide it ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this in the ViewDidLoad.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 45)];
label.text = @"HEADER VIEW";

self.tableView.tableHeaderView= label;
```

Comment: @Legolas : Thank you. I tried `self.tableView.tableHeaderView.hidden = YES` but then, there is a place left blank on the top of the tableView. How should I properly remove that blank space ?

Comment: Why do you use self.tableView.tableHeaderView.hidden = YES ?? This will make it blank.

Comment: @Legolas : Because sometimes I want some text there, sometimes not (when editing == YES). Setting text = @"" would not really solve the problem...

Comment: Could you post the code, where you might/might not want the text there ?

Comment: @Legolas : `- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animate { self.tableView.tableHeaderView.hidden = editing; ..... and some other code }`

Comment: I do not know what your goal is, and since you did not post much code, I think I can tell you the logic. You can do this. Keep it as an editable TextField by default, and carry out your program. Whenever you want textField to be hidden and want the label to appear (or vice versa), you can allocate the label it inside an if-else block and make it appear there. I could do this and show you how it would look if you can post the full code here. Even otherwise - This is the logic for your case.

Comment: @Legolas : The logic is just simple and there's no more code to show : I have some hard text in the header, and I want it to disapear when entering in editing mode, without any blank space. No more, nor less. And make it display again when exiting editing mode.

Comment: When you exit the editing mode, does it have the new String, or does it go back to the previous String ?